# Determine Bluetooth version for a specific session

Tags: android, winapi, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm writing a P2P communication app between Android and Windows devices, that relies on Bluetooth as the underline communication channel. I would like to check the version of the Bluetooth protocol being used for each session (i.e. 2.x, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, etc), in order to make security decisions accordingly (2.x is not very secure, 4.0 is more secure, 4.1 is most secure, etc).

How can that be achieved using API, on either Windows or Android? I'll have to check that for each session and session, because to my understanding, the Bluetooth version is determined as the minimum capability for both parties.

Answer (score 3):

First, the Bluetooth version after 2.1 SSP, e.g. 2.1,3.0,4.x, is basically same secure(however if you are talking about LE security that's another story), you do not need judge the LMP version actually.

Unfortunately Android does not export the remote version to apps, the lower level(Bluedroid) "BTM_ReadRemoteVersion", this function can get remote LMP version.

Your understanding is partial right, "Bluetooth version is determined as the minimum capability for both parties.", both host and controller's capability was defined by their minimum versions.

Comment: Thanks! Leaving LE aside, I read that Bluetooth 2.x uses E0 encryption, which was proven to be insecure, while Bluetooth 4.1 onwards using AES-CCM, which is considered secure. Doesn't that make 4.1 more secure than 2.x?

Comment: I am not an security expert, however AES-CCM encryption is more security then E0  does not mean E0 is not secure. We still need pick thee BLE up because only LE Secure Connections use the AES-CCM method, and the one reason to introduce AES-CCM to LE is that LE is not secure at BT4.0, i.e. it will transport LTK over air. so, what we need to be done is better to set the security mode as high(e.g. 4) as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to determine the version using Android logcat. During BT connection, I look for this line:

> bt_btif_dm: remote version info [aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff]: 8, 2, 100

The first digit (8) is the LMP version, which corresponds to a Core Bluetooth version. (In this case, 8 means Bluetooth 4.2)

This does not solve my problem completely, because starting at Android JB an app cannot read the logcat anymore (except for its own logs). However, this is a good start... will update if I find anything else.

Comment: Have you found anything else?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> Devices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
   s.add(bt.getVersion());
```

Comment: I don't see getVersion() method for BluetoothDevice class, and the latest mention for it in AOSP code seems to be in Android Donut (1.6), back in 2009

Comment: Its not available now, any other suggestions?